# Querying data from a WCF data service in Silverlight error

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, web-services, ado.net

I have a ADO.NET model entity that reflects an oracle database and a WCF Service that provides access to this ADO.NET model. In my WCF Service code, I have the following:

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
//config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyServiceOperation",ServiceOperationRights.All);
config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
```

I have added a reference to this service in my silverlight 5 application. Then in the following code, I am getting an error:

```
Uri WCFUri = new Uri(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, "WcfDataService.svc");
WCF_Service.Entities Database = new WCF_Service.Entities(WCFUri);

var buildings = from building in Config.Database.BUILDINGs
            select building.BLDG_ID;

var buildingsQuery = (DataServiceQuery<string>)buildings;

buildingsQuery.BeginExecute(buildingsResult =>
{
    foreach (string buildingId in buildingsQuery.EndExecute(buildingsResult))
        BuildingsList.Items.Add(new ListItem(buildingId.Trim(), false));
    BuildingListBusyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
}, null);
```

The error is:

```
Navigation properties can only be selected from a single resource. Specify a key predicate to restrict the entity set to a single instance.
```

I am lost on what the problem is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: I am not at my computer at work at the moment, but I think it is
var buildings = from building in Config.Database.BUILDINGs
            select building.BLDG_ID;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **ADO.NET Data Services** doesn't support projection feature.

Instead of selecting properties, you must select entities.

**WRONG**

```
var buildings = from building in Config.Database.BUILDINGs
            select building.BLDG_ID;
```

**CORRECT**

```
var buildings = from building in Config.Database.BUILDINGs
            select building;
```

*(I understand that in your case this correction pointless, but technically this is true)*

**OR** you can use shell, for example:

```
var buildings = from building in Config.Database.BUILDINGs
            select new { Id = building.BLDG_ID };
```